# iOS EventKit: Display calendar in a different section other than iCloud / On My iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, ekevent

Is there a way to create a new calendar in my app that will show up in a different section of the native iOS Calendar app?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/HQBi1Gi.png]

From the pic above, Facebook has its own section for its calendars, so does Hotmail, Gmail, etc.

At the moment, I am able to create calendars with sources EKSourceTypeLocal or EKSourceTypeCalDAV, which will display under the group "On My iPhone" or "iCloud" respectively. Can I create a new section here? It doesn't seem like you're able to create a new source, so I have no idea how to approach this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hotmail and Facebook and Gmail have sections because the user is subscribing to calendars from those services. To appear as a section, you'd need to run a CalDAV server that the user can subscribe to (in the Calendar application).

Comment: Bummer, I was hoping there was a simpler solution!

Comment: is it possible to create custom section with name of my application

Comment: What is CalDAV server?

Comment: @Kudos What is Wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CalDAV

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't create new sections for calanders to display under.

Comment: We have tried so many times to create section but we could only use existing sections